# How to remove every empty row from any SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with over 130 columns in it (don't ask--I didn't make it).  We need to remove every empty row (each field is empty) from this table without explicitly listing each column.  Ideally, I would like a solution that uses dynamic SQL and could be applied to any table.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

This will get you part way there at least:

```
DECLARE @myTable VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @MyTable = 'myTable'
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL + ' AND ','')+  '(' +quotename(COLUMN_NAME) + ' = '''' OR  ' +quotename(COLUMN_NAME) + ' IS NULL)'
FROM information_schema.columns 
WHERE table_NAME = @myTable

SET @SQL = 'DELETE FROM ' + quotename(@myTable) + ' WHERE ' + @sql
select @sql
```

Note the use of `QUOTENAME` to handle oddly named columns. Also note that this assumes all columns are string columns (or can be implicitly converted to a string). In your solution, you may want some conditional logic (using [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx)) to handle different datatypes e.g.

```
SELECT @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL + ' AND ','')+  '(' +quotename(COLUMN_NAME) + ' = ' + CASE WHEN data_type = 'int' then '0' when data_type = 'varchar' then '''' else '''' end + ' OR  ' +quotename(COLUMN_NAME) + ' IS NULL)'
    FROM information_schema.columns 
    WHERE table_NAME = @myTable
```

Answer (score 2):

This will remove the rows where every column is `null`.

```
-- Sample table
declare @T table
(
  Col1 int,
  Col2 datetime,
  Col3 bit,
  Col4 nvarchar(max)
)

-- Add sample data
insert into @T values
(null,      null, null, null),
(   1,      null, null, null),
(null, getdate(), null, null),
(null,      null,    1, null),
(null,      null, null, '')

-- Delete rows where all column values are null   
;with C(XmlCol) as
(
  select
    (select T.*
     for xml path('row'), type)
  from @T as T
)
delete from C
where C.XmlCol.exist('row/*') = 0
```

Result:

```
Col1        Col2                    Col3  Col4
----------- ----------------------- ----- ----------
1           NULL                    NULL  NULL
NULL        2011-11-23 14:09:42.770 NULL  NULL
NULL        NULL                    1     NULL
NULL        NULL                    NULL
```

https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/118893/

**Edit:**

If you want to remove **empty** string fields as well as `null` it would look like this:

```
;with C(XmlCol) as
(
  select
    (select T.*
     for xml path('row'), type)
  from @T as T
)
delete from C
where C.XmlCol.exist('row/*[. != ""]') = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider taking a look at the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` views which contain information about your tables, columns, keys and the like.  Using the `TABLES` and `COLUMNS` views should allow you to get a pretty robust solution to this.  Here is the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @SQL = COALESCE(@SQL + ' AND ','') + 
  (CASE 
    WHEN UPPER(DATA_TYPE) = 'INT'  THEN  ('(' +quotename(COLUMN_NAME) + ' = 0 OR  ' +quotename(COLUMN_NAME) + ' IS NULL)')
    WHEN UPPER(DATA_TYPE) = 'VARCHAR' THEN  ('(' +quotename(COLUMN_NAME) + ' = '''' OR  ' +quotename(COLUMN_NAME) + ' IS NULL)')
            -- More conditions are goes here
            -- Cover all data type (DATA_TYPE) used at your target table, or you may cover all existing data types
    ELSE '' 
    END)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE table_NAME = @targetTable
SET @SQL = 'DELETE FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@targetTable) + ' WHERE ' + @sql
SELECT @SQL
```

Answer (score 0):

For one off things like this I tend to use visual query builders or designers. They automatically put in all the field names and you can copy and paste IS NULL or = '' into a condition edit for each field and it produces the correct query. After building and testing them as a SELECT I convert them to DELETE or whatever other query type is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Parameterized mod of [@Elias Hossain](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1012747/elias-hossain)'s answer copied below.

```
create proc dbo.spDeleteRowsWhereAllColsAreNull
    @Schema nvarchar( 116 ),
    @Table nvarchar( 116 )
as
begin
    declare
            @RetMsg nvarchar( max ),
            @CountRows int,
            @ProcName nvarchar( 255 ) = N'dbo.spDeleteRowsWhereAllColsAreNull',
            @DynamicSql nvarchar( max ) = N'',
            @Schema_Table nvarchar( 255 ) = @Schema + N'.' + @Table,
            @Column nvarchar( 116 ),
            @Lb nchar( 1 ) = char( 13 ),
            @Tab nchar( 1 ) = char( 9 )

-- Check if target exists, else escape proc
    if exists( select * 
                from sys.tables
                where [object_id] = object_id( @Schema_Table ) )
    begin
        select @DynamicSql = 'delete from ' + @Schema_Table + N' where ' ;

-- Get all columns for target table into @DynamicSql
        select @DynamicSql += 
            @Tab + name+ N' is null and ' + @Lb
        from sys.columns
        where [object_id] = object_id( @Schema_Table ) ;

        set @DynamicSql = left( @DynamicSql, len( @DynamicSql ) - 6 ) ;
        -- print @DynamicSql ;

        exec sp_executesql @DynamicSql ;
        set @CountRows = @@rowcount ;
        set @RetMsg = @ProcName + N' executed in current Database ' + db_name() + N' on table ' + @Schema_Table + N'. ' + convert( nvarchar, @CountRows ) + N' row(s) deleted.' ;

-- Print results & return success
        print @RetMsg ;
        return 0 ;
    end
    else
    begin
-- Raiserror & return failure
        set @RetMsg = @Schema_Table + N' does not exist current Database ' + db_name() + N'. Execution FAILED!';
        raiserror( @RetMsg, 11, -1 ) ;
        return -1 ;
    end ;

end ;
go
```